# Phaser Arcade Lagging Body

Tags: javascript, game-engine, game-physics, phaser-framework

I am currently making a continuous scroller game using Phaser, With arcade physics. I have a stationary player object in the center that moves up and down, To create the illusion that it is moving I use a tween to bring obstacles across the screen: 
`game.add.tween(block).to({ x: 0-(height/blocksize) }, 5000-speed, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None).start();`

To allow the tween to do this and to allow the player to be stopped by the obstacles I set the body to be immovable:

```
block.body.allowGravity = false;
block.body.moves = false;
block.body.immovable = true;
```

This seemed to work well, However, I then noticed that the player sunk slightly into the side on a collision:

[image: Lagging body]

I then tried to manually offset the body using this code in the update loop:

```
b[i].body.x = b[i].world.x-10;
```

And although this does allow the body to be near perfectly aligned, The player does not collide with the body sideways:

[image: Sideways collision]

[image: Vertical collision]

[image: Sideways collision]

So the main problem is that when the player( A sprite. ), hits one of the moving blocks( Another sprite. ), It appears to sink slightly into it. This is due to the fact that the physics body of the moving block is lagging slightly behind the visual sprite. It may be worth noting that I am using the phaser arcade physics engine.

Comment: Could you edit your question to further clarify what the problem is? What is the player, what is the collision etc?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hopefully it is clearer now?

Comment: Which is the player, the square or the rect?

Comment: The player is the square, The physics body of the player is aligned well, However the obstacles physics bodys are misaligned. Thanks!